# Using \mathptmx but keeping the original Sans-Serif font

Tags: mathptmx

I like Times New Roman font so I use the `mathptmx` package. But I noticed that text in the `\textsf{}` looks different (they look more like Arial in Word) from what they should be without `mathptmx`. Can you guys help me this? I like Times but I prefer the original Sans-Serif font. (Keep in mind that I don't mean to change the whole document to Sans-Serif, I just want those in `textsf{}` look like they are without `mathptmx`).

Comment: If you use Xe/LuaLaTeX, you can use `fontspec` and `\setmainfont` to Times New Roman without changing the sans font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, per standard, for Times New Roman font family, Helvetica family are the default Sans font, for this, you can use the default package `helvet`

Comment: mathptmx doesn't change the sans serif font. Something else must be doing this, but as you don't show any code ...

Comment: You shouldn't use `mathptmx` to begin with: it's a 30-year-old hack to provide emulation of Times for text and math using limited resources. There are much better modern alternatives.